# Cookie expiration date equals -1

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm retrieving some cookies information and some of them have the `expires` property set to `-1`, does anyone knows what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://webpy.org/cookbook/cookies

> Any negative number will expire the cookie immediately. Any positive number is the number of seconds that the cookie will last (3600 would result in an hour long cookie)

Though it's worth checking if the cookies have a `max-age` set

https://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/

> Every browser that supports max-age will ignore the expires regardless of it’s value, and likewise, Internet Explorer will ignore the max-age and just use expires